# Using Laplace in this circuit, how to find part C(Vx)?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I used Laplace transformation to find Vx(s), but I tried to find Vx(t) using the definition, but it didn't work with me. Is there another way to find it?

And about part d, I can use the limit right?

at t<0 : Vc=0 and IL=1A

at t>0 : I transferred all elements to Laplace , the two voltage source became (5/s) and the capacitor resistance is (2/s) , the inductor resistance is (4s) and inductor voltage is (-1) , then I found Vx(s) using nodal  which equal to Vx(s)=(10(s^2)-s+5)/(2(s^3)+4(s^2)+s) , is the answer right or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You used the correct Laplace equivalences for the elements, but the transfer function seems wrong in the numerator. First, the equivalent impedance seen from the left to right, is the resistor parallel with the inductance, \$Z_{RL}\$, and the impedance seen from the right to left is the resistor parallel with the capacitor, \$Z_{RC}\$ (see the picture below). Now the transfer function becomes:

$$\begin{align}
Z_{RL}&=\dfrac{4s}{4s+1} \\
Z_{RC}&=\dfrac{2}{s+2} \\
V_x&=\dfrac{5}{s}\left(\dfrac{Z_{RL}}{\dfrac{2}{s}+Z_{RL}}+\dfrac{Z_{RC}}{4s+Z_{RC}}\right)&=\dfrac{1}{s}\cdot\dfrac{10s^2+5}{2s^2+4s+1} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

If \$V_x\$ is related to a unity input, \$V_x=H(s)\$. To verify this:

[image: test]

The sources are `I1` and `C1`, which form an integrator, and together with the value `ac 5` form the Laplace equivalent of \$\dfrac{5}{s}\$.

For the c) part you have two ways you can solve this: inverse Laplace, or differential equations. Since you already have the transfer function, it might be easier to apply the inverse Laplace. Might not. Here's one way to do it. First, expand into partial fractions:

$$\begin{align}
(1)&\rightarrow\dfrac{5}{s}-\dfrac{20}{2s^2+4s+1}&=U(s)-A(s) \tag{2} \\
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{U(s)\}&=5 \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

The roots for the denominator of the second term, \$A(s)\$, are real roots, \$\{-0.293, -1.707\}\$, therefore it's an overdamped case, with the inverse Laplace:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{A(s)\}=10\sqrt{2}\sinh\left(\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-t} \tag{4}$$

Combine (3) and (4) to give the resulting response:

$$h(t)=5-10\sqrt{2}\sinh\left(\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-t} \tag{6}$$

However, the verification seems a bit awkward. Building the time domain circuit shows slightly different results:

[image: time]

OTOH, using the IFFT on the frequency response from the 1st picture shows a match, though LTspice considers the electrical, rather than the mathematical equivalent (hence the `time` correction):

[image: IFFT]